# How to contribute to a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, command-line, rubygems

I am trying to contribute to a Ruby gem and I don't understand how to test a local gem without using a globally installed gem.

The gem I want to contribute to is a command line interface gem. I clone the gem into a directory then `cd` into that directory. However, when I run commands in the terminal when I'm in the cloned project directory it still uses the global gem. I've even run

`gem uninstall gemname`

then while inside the newly cloned gem directory I redo

`gem install gemname`.

No matter what changes I make to the gem, I can't see the results or what my contributions are doing because it's always running the global gem.

When I do try to type a command line command that is supposed to interact with the gem while in the cloned gem directory I get:

`-bash: ~/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin/githubrepo: No such file or directory`

I've done a ton of research but I'm just not getting it. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gem install gemname` will look for a .gem file in the current directory. If not found it will look for it on the web.

`gem install --local /path/to/your/gemname.gem` will allow you to target a particular directory. You may need to `gem build gemname.gemspec` first, so it has your changes.

Instead of doing this, I would write tests in the gem directory itself. It's likely that when running code in there, you can simply `require 'gemname'` in Ruby to get the gem functionality.

If it's a well-written gem, it should have tests already. They will most likely be in a directory called test or spec. Have a look at these tests and try to carry on in that style to test your changes. This will make your code changes far far more likely to be accepted as a pull request.